# How to do batch reverse Geocoding ?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I want to do reverse Geocode for 15 times. I constructed an array of JSON and tried to query it:

var data = [0: {lat: 39.11494064331055, lng: -76.47647857666016}

1: {lat: 42.51514434814453, lng: -88.07449340820312}

2: {lat: 34.67732620239258, lng: -118.29962921142578}

3: {lat: 34.022525787353516, lng: -84.55994415283203}

4: {lat: 49.9931755065918, lng: -2.670909881591797}];

```
geoCoder.geocode({ 'location': data}, function (results, status) {
        //console.log(results);
    });
```

I want to do in batch but I am getting an error:

InvalidValueError: in property location: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Any solutions on how to do it in a batch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple, Googles Map API expects the data to be their own class, so you cant just create an object with lat/lng. instead just create an object with [LatLong](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) class.
Simply like this:
`myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -34, lng: 151});`

Comment: No, it is used to construct the latlng object but when i tried it had nothing but prototype inside.  How can i do the batch request ?